# How can I register the Scala Jackson Module in Riak-Java?

Tags: java, scala, jackson, riak

Needed to have support for Scala Lists and Options when storing to Riak. Looks like the Scala Module for Jackson would work for this. However, how would it be hooked into the object mapper in Riak? Not sure if I need to override something or if there's an annotation that can easily solve it.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few releases ago I added a `getObjectMapper()` method to the `JSONConverter` as someone had requested it. This is the `Converter` that is used for fetch/store operations if you're passing in POJOs and haven't created and passed in your own.

You'd want to instantiate the `JSONConverter` yourself and get the `ObjectMapper` from it:

```
JsonConverter<MyClass> converter = new JSONConverter<MyClass>(MyClass.class, bucketName);
ObjectMapper om = converter.getObjectMapper();
```

You can now register the module with the `ObjectMapper` and then use the `JSONConverter` with your fetch/store operations (using the `withConverter()` method of the `StoreObject` and `FetchObject`).

I think that's what you're looking for. If you needed more control over serializing/deserializing your objects you could also write your own `Converter`- I've written a cookbook entry on the subject here: https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/wiki/Using-a-custom-Converter

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I was in the midst of cooking a custom branch that was going nowhere. Is that also going to be in the new cookbook wiki?

Comment: Actually, scratch that, perhaps I can update the docs myself (after a road full of lessons with Scala). :)

Comment: It's in the Javadoc for the `JSONConverter`, of course. There's actually an issue someone opened on github where they have asked that a constructor be added that takes the `ObjectMapper` as an argument. Same result, but a little less clunky. Just hasn't been a priority to get to it. If you'd like to write up something scala specific for the cookbook I'd be happy to add it.

Comment: I just might do that. On that note, I noticed that annotations have gone awry when I started using Jackson 2.1.2. So I'm sure there are others out there who need help! LOL